# String that ends with .html

Tags: regex

I'm not good at regex and need some help. I want regex to match strings which starts with **"** and ends with **.html"**

For example this string:
`"index.html"`

... should match:
`index.html`

How can I do this using regex?

**EDIT:** I need all strings that ends with .html

Comment: Are you validating entire strings, or are you looking for sub-matches within a longer string?

Comment: I couldn't understand what you mean

Comment: I was asking about your input. Are you trying to find all the matching strings in a larger text (for example, in a webpage), or is the input limited to one string, and you want to check whether that string follows the rules of the regex. I guess it's the former, based on your accepted answer. If not, be aware that that regex would also match if only a part of the string fits the regex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
"[^"]+\.html"
```

You need:

- literal double quotes at each end (`"` has no special significance in regex)
- `[^"]+` meaning "at least one non-double quote"
- an escaped dot `\.` (a dot alone would mean "any character")
- literal `html`

If you don't want to include the quotes in the match:

```
 (?<=")[^"]+\.html(?=")
```

Comment: hi, your code didn't work at all. I'm using Notepad++ What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @onurcano22 maybe I misunderstood your question. Do you want to match `index.html` within quotes, but anywhere in the text? (I assumed the *entire* input/line has to be this)

Comment: yes, I have many links in text and want to match all links between ""

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you want match word (consisting numbers too) which starts with `"` symbol and ends with `.html` followed by `"`.
Try following

```
(?<=")\w+\.html(?=")
```

Comment: I were suggested that character sets were not necessary. thanks @TimPietzcker

Comment: hi, I edited the question. your code only matches string that contains "index". thanks for the answer.

Comment: @onurcano22 probably, but it marches desired result here. [see example](https://regex101.com/r/dS5cX8/1)